# msctls_progress32 window properties on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I want to read the contents of a "msctls_progress32" in a window. I don't know how to access its content, as I don't know about the propeties. Like, textbox has text, and a label has a caption, how do I access the contents of the "msctls_progress32". I need to read the last line of the contents and then do some procession, like run another program, if the content now reads "Success". Following are the control identifiers. I'm using Python 2.72.

I want to read the contents of a "msctls_progress32" in a window. I don't know how to access its content, as I don't know about the propeties. Like, textbox has text, and a label has a caption, how do I access the contents of the "msctls_progress32". I need to read the last line of the contents and then do some procession, like run another program, if the content now reads "Success". Following are the control identifiers. I'm using Python 2.72.

```
>>> app.Cm3wsd.print_control_identifiers()
Control Identifiers:
Button - '&Exit'   (L766, T594, R819, B618)
    '&Exit' '&ExitButton' 'Button' 'Button0' 'Button1'
Static - 'File to &download'   (L459, T366, R537, B379)
    'File to &download' 'File to &downloadStatic' 'Static'
Edit - 'C:\\Users\\pvathark\\Desktop\\sampleABC123.hex'   (L459, T384, R767, B407)
    'Edit' 'File to &downloadEdit'
Button - '&Browse...'   (L768, T384, R821, B407)
    '&Browse...' '&Browse...Button' 'Button2'
Button - '&Monitor Status'   (L459, T415, R819, B578)
    '&Monitor Status' '&Monitor StatusGroupBox' 'GroupBox'
ListBox - ''   (L474, T439, R804, B553)
    'File to &downloadListBox' 'ListBox'
Button - '&Start'   (L550, T594, R603, B618)
    '&Start' '&StartButton' 'Button3'
Button - 'Run'   (L694, T594, R747, B618)
    'Button5' 'Run' 'RunButton'

**msctls_progress32 - 'Progress1'   (L474, T561, R804, B569)
    '&Monitor StatusProgress' 'Progress'**

Button - '&Configure...'   (L466, T594, R531, B617)
    '&Configure...' '&Configure...Button' 'Button6'
```